# navigation.navigate('Home') showing some error in typescript

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When I use useNavigation or from props { navigation } for navigate between screen using navigation.navigate('Home') the typescript return error Argument of type '"Main"' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: never; key?: string | undefined; params: never; merge?: boolean | undefined; }' what does it mean?

below is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')}>Navigate</Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Home);
```

previously i used react navigation v5 and working find with that method

thanks for your help

Comment: `navigation.navigate({...params})`

Comment: Take a look Specifying default types for useNavigation, Link, ref etc at: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#specifying-default-types-for-usenavigation-link-ref-etc

Comment: This [example from react-navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) helped me understand what types are needed.

Answer (score 46):

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```js
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Main: undefined;
  Home: undefined;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={Main}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

then in your code to do something like this:

```js
type homeScreenProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<homeScreenProp>();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')}>Navigate</Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should put some explanation as well. Makes it easier for others to understand the issue and solution

Comment: ok, maybe this article can help.   https://benjaminwoojang.medium.com/react-navigation-with-typescript-270dfa8d5cad

Comment: I'm just do this but that is not working

navigate function always return error message in Typescript, but not error in the application

Comment: `Cannot find name 'RootStackParamList'.` I got this error when i tried

Comment: @RahmanHaroon you need to import it from the first file. (It's exported here: `export type RootStackParamList` )

Comment: It's not working. I get the error: `Property 'navigate' does not exist on type 'HomeScreenProps'`

Answer (score 21):

This is because you must specify this type, as this will ensure type-safety.

Solution:

1 - Type checking the navigator

```js
// root.routes.tsx

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};
```

```js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

2 - Specify a global type for your root navigator

```js
// navigation.d.ts

import { RootStackParamList } from '../routes/root.routes';

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList { }
  }
}
```

3 - Use it!

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();

navigation.navigate('Home');
```

4- Extra! If you need to grab a parameter:

```js
import { useRoute, RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../routes/root.routes';

const route = useRoute<RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>>();

const id = route.params.userId;
```

Refs:

- @acro5piano answer from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9741
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#annotating-usenavigation

Comment: I am facing errr in line const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
Parsing error: Unexpected token (81:56)eslint
Expression expected.ts(1109)

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem, it will help for now, but it's not the correct typing:

```js
type Nav = {
  navigate: (value: string) => void;
}

const { navigate } = useNavigation<Nav>()

function foo() {
  navigate("Home")
}
```

Comment: Yeah, who really needs all of that type-checking, right?

Answer (score 8):

While the other answers cover a good amount, I think I may add to this by describing usage in the `useNavigation` hook as well as passing the `{navigation}` through props to a screen.

**First, setup the Stack Navigator**:

```js
/**
* Types for Stack Navigator.
*/
export type StackParamList = {
  Main: undefined;
  Home: undefined;
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator<StackParamList>();
```

- When using the `useNavigation` hook:

```js
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";

/**
 * Types for the Stack Navigator.
 */
export type StackNavigation = StackNavigationProp<StackParamList>;

const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigation>();
```

- When passing the navigation down as a prop in a screen:

```js
/**
 * Types for passing the navigation props to screens in the Bottom Tab Navigator.
*/
export type StackNavigationProps = {
  navigation: StackNavigation;
};

const SomeScreenInTheStack = ({ navigation }: StackNavigationProps) => {
...
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is this:

1. create a file @types/index.ts
   inside this file paste de code:

```
  routeNames: never[];
};

export type navigationProps = {
  navigate: (screen?: string) => void;
  goBack: () => void;
  reset: (index: number, routeNames: Routes[]) => void;
};
```

2. Now you just need to use the navigationProps as the generic of useNavigation example:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

 const navigation = useNavigation<navigationProps>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way for this is:

navigation.navigate('Main' as never)}

Answer (score -2):

You can just put a Type on the screen name. Just like:

```
const handleContinue = () => navigation.navigate('Login' as never);
```

Comment: That's not a good practice. I'm not the downvoter.